# How to keep image list in a line without breaking?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I have a div container and its width is 150px.
The div has a table and its width is variable with its content that is a image list.
If the size of image list is larger than 150px then <td> will break a new line.
How to keep the image list in a line without breaking?
Our code can work on chrome but it can't work on IE9.
Following is my html code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <title>test</title>

        <style text="text/css">
            .thumbnail{
                float:left;                
            }

            .NoBreak{ 
                white-space:nowrap;
                word-break:keep-all 
            }
        </style>        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style='width:150px;overflow:hidden;border:1px solid #ff0000;'>
            <table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'><tr height='40'><td nowrap class='NoBreak'>
                <img src='b1347546434941/s1347546434942/1209135051ed48bc89d.jpg' class='thumbnail' width='30' height='40'/>
                <img src='b1347546434941/s1347546434942/1209135051ed48bc89d.jpg' class='thumbnail' width='30' height='40'/>
                <img src='b1347546434941/s1347546434942/1209135051ed48bc89d.jpg' class='thumbnail' width='30' height='40'/>
                <img src='b1347546434941/s1347546434942/1209135051ed48bc89d.jpg' class='thumbnail' width='30' height='40'/>
                <img src='b1347546434941/s1347546434942/1209135051ed48bc89d.jpg' class='thumbnail' width='30' height='40'/>
                <img src='b1347546434941/s1347546434942/1209135051ed48bc89d.jpg' class='thumbnail' width='30' height='40'/>
                <img src='b1347546434941/s1347546434942/1209135051ed48bc89d.jpg' class='thumbnail' width='30' height='40'/>
                <img src='b1347546434941/s1347546434942/1209135051ed48bc89d.jpg' class='thumbnail' width='30' height='40'/>
                <img src='b1347546434941/s1347546434942/1209135051ed48bc89d.jpg' class='thumbnail' width='30' height='40'/>
                <img src='b1347546434941/s1347546434942/1209135051ed48bc89d.jpg' class='thumbnail' width='30' height='40'/>
            </td></tr></table>    
        </div>    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you using a table, with only one cell/row?  This should be an unordered list.  You can remove the bullet with CSS if you want.

Comment: And ie likes to break on white space. Remove the line feeds

Comment: Why are you using tables at all?